# Accessing vagrant dev environment

Tags: dns, vagrant

We've just started using Vagrant for dev environments for individuals, but found a pain point with trying to show other people what you're working on. I.e. Hey Bob, check out dave.dev.example.com (Vagrant box) and try the login.

At the moment the Vagrant boxes are using bridged networking, so have an IP on the local network, but we're having to put hosts file entries in.

How have others worked around this problem? At the moment I'm thinking either push a record into a local BIND server or having devs commit to a branch and checkout on a test server.

Comment: Have you tried [Vagrant Share](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/http.html)?

Comment: I didn't know about Vagrant share, it looks cool, but our web app runs on specific hostnames. Maybe I need to fix that up.